# Как поменять z-index для HeatMap?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

При одновременном использовании "Регионов" от Yandex и HeatMap, тепловая карта оказывается под слоем регионов. Настройки в API не нашел. Как можно поменять z-index для HeatMap? (Классические балуны и метки отображаются поверх "регионов").

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу такой путь:

```
// Тут добавляем карту.
// Меняем zIndex у подложки, чтобы она была ниже полигонов.
myMap.layers.each(function(l){
    l.options.set('zIndex', 0)
})
// Добавляем регионы.
ymaps.borders.load('RU', {
                lang: 'ru',
                quality: 2
            }).then(function (result) {
                lastCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(null, {
                    // Меняем пейн полигонов.
                    pane: 'ground'
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < result.features.length; i++) {
                    var geoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject(result.features[i]);
                    lastCollection.add(geoObject);
                }
                myMap.geoObjects.add(lastCollection);
            })
//Тут добавляем тепловые карты
```

Но нужно протестировать, что это адекватно работает=)